# Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller required by directive , can't be found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, slim-lang

I keep getting this error from a directive that requires another directive.  What I don't understand is that this code works on other pages without issue.  here is some code:

The directive that is blowing up:

```
newco.directive 'signupShippingForm', [
  () ->
    {
    templateUrl: '/pages/signup/billing/shipping_form'
    require: ['signupShippingForm', '^addressScrub']
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) ->
      ctrl = ctrls[0]
      addressScrubCtrl = ctrls[1]
      ctrl.updateAddress = () ->
        addressScrubCtrl.scrubAddress()
    controller: ['$scope', 'productService', 'UsStatesCodes'
      ($scope, productService, UsStatesCodes) ->
        ctrl = @
        $scope.shippingPackages = productService.shippingPackage()
        $scope.states = UsStatesCodes

        $scope.toggleBillingInfo = ()->
          $scope.billingOption.same = !$scope.billingOption.same
          if $scope.billingOption.same
            _.extend $scope.shippingInfo, $scope.billingInfo
          else
            $scope.shippingInfo = {}

        ctrl.showShippingToggle = !$scope.showSimpleForm

        @
    ]
    }
]
```

the error I am receiving is:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'addressScrub', required by directive 'signupShippingForm', can't be found!
```

my HTML where it is blowing up is:

```
   form(name="updateShippingForm" ng-submit="save(updateShippingForm.$valid, billingInfo, shippingInfo)" autofill-sync)

      billing-form-prefill
        address-scrub
          .container
            signup-billing-form(ng-if="true == false")
            signup-simple-billing-form(ng-if="true == false")

            hr

          signup-shipping-form ng-if="true == true"

        signup-billing-package(ng-if="true == false")

        signup-billing-agreement
```

So address-scrub is a parent of signupShipping form so I would think the ^ syntax would be finding it.  The ng-ifs are there because I literally copied the HTMl from another form where this setup is currently working, so I added those to disable those elements.

The controller for the page is just:

```
@newco.controller 'UpdateShippingController', ($location, $routeParams, $scope, userService, BillingInfo) ->
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried requiring `'^^addressScrub'`?

Comment: Yes I did try that but I get the same error.  Thank you for your reply.